# Java classes in IDL files?

Tags: java, eclipse, libreoffice

I want to modify an existing LibreOffice extension located at: http://people.freedesktop.org/~vmiklos/2012/lpsp/

I've cloned the git repository into eclipse, but i immediately get alot of errors saying that classes are missing.

I can see that these classes are imported but the path to the files leads to a bunch of IDL files. They have the correct class names but what can I do with and IDL file?

Comment: run this command in terminal to compile the IDL classes `idlj -fall filename.idl`